# assign value to checkbox using loop php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

The $file-name should be for example: a.pdf,b.pdf,c.pdf,d.pdf respectively. 
But why I cannot assign the value into the checkbox?

### please help/__\

```
while($row = Mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $file-name = $row['Name'] . ".pdf";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='q1[]'value=<?php echo $filename ?>' > </td>";
}
```

Comment: You're setting `$file-name`, and printing `$filename`. Those are two separate variables - use the latter.

Comment: Try to use `$filename` instead of `$file-name` when you declarate the variable...

Comment: another note is that use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to get associative array such as `$row['name']`

Comment: variables can not contain hyphens '-' .... that is the subtraction operator.

Comment: Also, You `echo` into an `echo` ?

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above, try the following:

```
while($row = Mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $filename = $row['Name'] . ".pdf";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='q1[]' value='".$filename."' /> </td>";
}
```

As the comments to your question mentioned you were assigning `$file-name` (an invalid variable name in PHP) and trying to use a (presumably) unassigned variable: `$filename` you also were missing an opening single-quote for the value attribute which could prevent it from properly rendering, and you can use string concatenation instead of trying to echo-inside-an-echo.